# Swift 4 shouldChangeCharactersIn only show length = 12

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have `textfield` ,`shouldChangeCharactersIn` codes im using barcode, system and my barcode codes == 12 characters. I want to show only 12 characters in my string if barcode small 12 characters or big must be return false or clean text field . my codes under below. When I using barcode if my barcodes 12 characters working fine , but if I read 12 character low don't clear textfield ,

> How can I fix it ?

My codes under below.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let length = (Mytext.text?.characters.count)! - range.length + string.characters.count
        if length == 13 {

            print("Mytext=\(Mytext.text!)")
            Mytext.text = ""

            return true

        }else {


            return true
        }


    }
```

Output when read 12 characters barcode shows success !
When read 12 characters low don't clear Mytext field , and when I read again adding +

Comment: Try changing `length == 13` to `length != 12`.

Comment: @AllenR I did, output=  Mytext=
Mytext=3
Mytext=4
Mytext=6
Mytext=0
Mytext=7
Mytext=1
Mytext=3
Mytext=9
Mytext=3
Mytext=8
Mytext=4
Mytext=5

Comment: What output are you expecting? Seems to me like you are saying that if you get a character count other than 12, then you want to clear the text field.

Comment: @AllenR I want this , when read barcode if have 12 characters will shows if not equal == 12 will be clear Mytext.

Comment: What is the var MyText here? You could also try `textField.text = ""` to clear it.

Comment: I think you actually want this delegate `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` then you will check if `textField.text.length != 12` and clear it then.

Comment: @AllenR I did don't clear , example:  barcode readed = 12345, after again read, adding 12345+ and output  1234512345 like..

Comment: You will have to add more code then. I cannot see how that would be happening from the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (string != "" && textField.text?.count == 12) {

        print("Mytext = \(textField.text!)")
        textField.text = ""
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set replacement string to "" blank string

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let length = (Mytext.text?.characters.count)! - range.length + string.characters.count
    if length == 13 {

        print("Mytext=\(Mytext.text!)")
        Mytext.text = ""

        return true

    }else {


        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: I did says , string = "" , line error - > Cannot assign to value: 'string' is a 'let' constant